# Retrieving category by name where name has ampersand inside

Tags: php, magento

I'm ripping my hear out where I am trying to retrieve a category by the name of the category. I know normally in order to do this, you would do:

```
$currentCategoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Hello');
```

However I have categories with '&' inside such as 'Cards & Invites' meaning there is a possiblity that no results would be returned, meaning I cannot further manipulate the category.

Is there a way to esacpe the ampersand in order for me to actually insert the category name therefore be able to retrieve the category I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this in version 1.7 by naming the one of my categories "Household & Items". After re-running the index then calling the following returns the category desired:

```
$currentCategoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Household & Items');
```

After tracing this function back to where it builds the database query I have noticed that in this example the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` class will use `addcslashes` on the value. This should be more than enough for your example.

```
protected function _quote($value)
{
    if (is_int($value)) {
        return $value;
    } elseif (is_float($value)) {
        return sprintf('%F', $value);
    }
    return "'" . addcslashes($value, "\000\n\r\\'\"\032") . "'";
}
```

Comment: @DavidManners- Thanks for your help with the problem. I think your one got closest to the solution that I tried. I ended up finding out that the original method that got the Category name required for the search had the following, Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($category->getName()). So I removed the htmlEscape call then it worked fine. Cheers for that. I'll mark this answer as correct as it was the closest one to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is either a bug or an intended behavior that makes the `loadByAttribute` method not work in conjunction with some models.

One of which happens to be the `catalog/category` model. I suggest using `load('Category name', 'name')` in stead of `loadByAttribute('name', 'Category name')`.

Before making this suggestion I tested both methods on a live production environment containing `magento 1.7`, only `load` worked.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested, with the load method but that I get this error, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /Users/koramaiku/Sites/divana/divana/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 954. Any how I managed to nail the problem and it's all working fine. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Although Magento do not have anu such problem, but as you are getting one.. please try as follows:

try using "" instead of ''

if not working try using

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags("name & address"))));
```

You can also try to add following line to your htaccess file

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

Also

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

else

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

try checking above actions.

Regards

Comment: -1 As you said escaping in general and/or HTML entity escaping should have absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: I have not said that this will work because of escaping, instead i said that magento does not show such behaviour in general and few ideas to start with to debug the issue.. although thanks for downvoting

Comment: IMO answering should provide a solution or guidance regarding how to obtain a solution. Conversely collateral (useful) things belong in comments. The up/down voting system is here to offer motivation for creating quality content, there's no need to (sarcastically or otherwise) thank anyone for voting.